# Rspec: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries should be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Testing filling in the contact form without filling in one of the required fields in one test and then filling in the honey_pot field in another test. The tests when valid info is filled in are passing, but the two other specs are failing.

**Update** I've been running the test a couple of times and sometimes all the tests pass. Other times, the same specs fail.

Terminal output

```
  3) Pages Home page it should behave like all static pages Footer Contact Form when honeypot is filled does not send an email
     Failure/Error: expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty
       expected empty? to return true, got false
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:69
     # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Pages Home page it should behave like all static pages Footer Contact Form when fields are not filled does not send an email
     Failure/Error: expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty
       expected empty? to return true, got false
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:69
     # ./spec/requests/pages_spec.rb:38:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'                                                                                                                                    

describe "Pages" do                                                                                                                                      

  subject { page }                                                                                                                                       

  shared_examples_for "all static pages" do |path_name|                                                                                                  
    before { visit send(path_name) }                                                                                                                     

    describe "Footer" do                                                                                                                                 

      describe "Contact Form" do                                                                                                                         
        it { should have_selector('h7', text: 'Contact Us') }                                                                                            

        context "when a valid message" do                                                                                                                

          it "sends an email" do                                                                                                                         
            post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message)                                                                                  
            expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to eq(["#{ENV["MVP_USERNAME"]}"])                                                              
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear                                                                                                          
          end                                                                                                                                            
        end                                                                                                                                              

        context "when fields are not filled" do                                                                                                          
          it "does not send an email" do                                                                                                                 
            post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message, name: '', body: '')                                                              
            expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty                                                                                            
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear                                                                                                          
          end                                                                                                                                            
        end                           
      end                                                                                                                                              

        context "when honeypot is filled" do                                                                                                             
          it "does not send an email" do                                                                                                                 
            post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message, sweet_honey: 'bot')                                                              
            expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty                                                                                            
            ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear                                                                                                          
          end                                                                                                                                            
        end                                                                                                                                              
      end                                                                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                                  
  end                

  describe "Home page" do                                                                                                                                
    before { visit root_path }                                                                                                                           
    it_should_behave_like "all static pages", :root_path                                                                                                 
    it { should have_text('Quality Cars') }                                                                                                              
    it { should have_title('Misawa Used Cars - Misawa Auto Sales') }                                                                                     

    describe "Send a message" do                                                                                                                         
      before do                                                                                                                                          
        fill_in "Name", with: 'name'                                                                                                                     
        fill_in "Email", with: 'email@example.com'                                                                                                       
        fill_in "Phone", with: '999-9999-9999'                                                                                                           
        fill_in "Body", with: 'Hello'                                                                                                                    
        click_button "Send"                                                                                                                              
      end                                                                                                                                                

      describe "after the message is sent" do                                                                                                            

        it "should render the desired page with a flash" do                                                                                              
          expect(page).to have_text('Quality Cars')                                                                                                      
          expect(page).to have_title('Misawa Used Cars - Misawa Auto Sales')                                                                             
          expect(page).to have_selector('.alert-box.success')                                                                                            
        end                                                                                                                                              
      end                                                                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                                  
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the specs passing by clearing the `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` before and after each of the specs where I tested the deliveries. I also rewrote the tests to make it DRYer using the `before(:each)` and `after(:each)` methods describe in [Rspec's documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks#define-before-and-after-blocks-in-configuration). **Update** Even better, `around(:each)`

Improved Specs

```
  describe "Contact Form" do                                                                                                                         
    it { should have_selector('h7', text: 'Contact Us') }                                                                                            

    describe "send a message" do                                                                                                                     
      around(:each) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }                                                                                                                                                                                   

      context "when a valid message" do                                                                                                              
        it "sends an email" do                                                                                                                       
          post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message)                                                                                
          expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to).to eq(["#{ENV["MVP_USERNAME"]}"])                                                            
        end                                                                                                                                          
      end                                                                                                                                            

      context "when fields are not filled" do                                                                                                        
        it "does not send an email" do                                                                                                               
          post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message, name: '', body: '')                                                            
          expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty                                                                                          
        end                                                                                                                                          
      end                                                                                                                                            

      context "when honeypot is filled" do                                                                                                           
        it "does not send an email" do                                                                                                               
          post contact_create_path, message: attributes_for(:message, sweet_honey: 'bot')                                                            
          expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries).to be_empty                                                                                          
        end                                                                                                                                          
      end                                                                                                                                            
    end                                                                                                                                              
  end
```

Comment: Note that around(:each) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear } will not call your testcases, its not a good practice!!! You should be doing  around(:each) { |example| ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear ; example.run ; ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }

see [around docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/around-hooks)